# mandar datos de un getElementById a variable PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un código que me traduce un texto proveniente de una variable PHP y me lo pone traducido mdentro de un 'div id="translation"'
Necesito mandar este texto a una BD y para ello quiero ponerlo en una variable PHP.
Supongo que debe ser muy sencillo pero, no sé como hacerlo.
Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Aquí está el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    $original = 'Goat cheese salad with tomato';
?>
    <div id="$original"><?php echo $original ?></div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      function translateText(response) {
        document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      var $original = escape(document.getElementById("$original").innerHTML);

      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key= -- Mi API key --  &source=en&target=es&callback=translateText&q=' + $original;
      newScript.src = source;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es "enviar" esa traducción al php para que se guarde en bbdd, lo  que puedes hacer es ponerlo en un formulario, y luego enviarlo, o enviarlo por ajax a un php para que lo guarde.

Comment: No hay ninguna manera diferente de getElementById para guardar directamente la traducción en una variable PHP?

Comment: Lo he puesto así y no me funciona: 
<form  method= "POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="tradu.php";?>
  <div id="translation"></div>
 <button type='submit' ></button>

Answer (score 1):

He hecho una pequeña adaptación de tu código para explicarte mi respuesta, no se del todo si te funcionará, pero ahí va.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $original = 'Goat cheese salad with tomato';
    ?>
    <div id="$original"><?php echo $original ?></div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      function translateText(response) {
        document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + " Ensalada de queso con tomete";
      }
      translateText("original");
      var traducido = document.getElementById("translation").innerText; 
    </script>
  <?php
     $valorPHP = "<script>document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', traducido)</script>";
     echo "valorPHP = ".$valorPHP;
  ?>
```

Como ves se trata de hacer que el valor de la variable lo escriba Javascript.
Te puede servir como punto de partida, aunque el método habitual es usar ajax o fetch, que permite enviar y receibir datos de una fuente externa (en tu caso un php) sin necesidad de recargar la página .

Comment: Gracias, ahora si tengo la variable, pero no me lo traduce. Has sustituido response.data.translations[0].translatedText por la traducción...

Comment: Si, no tengo apikey para probar con google translate, así que he usado la técnica caja negra: he escrito lo que me debería responder (supongo que ese valor lo sacaras del api de google translate).  Es decir, una vez consigas el valor de la variable este método te lo pasa a variable php. Lo importante es el código php donde está el $valorPHP.

Comment: Si pongo el código bien para que lo traduzca, me devuelve valorPHP = undefined

Comment: Te puedo mandar la API Key por privado?

Comment: Vale, como quieras. Te he respondido al correo.

Comment: AIzaSyA2D7YxcGaW_6g6APPcbsemv2AOxdFrwCY

Comment: Aqui tienes la API para provar, luego ya la cambiaré

Comment: Voy a cambiar la solución, esta solución no es aplicable en este caso por la llamada asíncrona al API. En la nueva añado una llamada con fetch a un archivo, translate_bd.php, en el que tendrías que colocar el código para guardar en la base de datos. Este podría devolver el mismo dato que recibe y lo anota en el bloque div (es lo que hace el ejemplo que te pongo).

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución es más adecuada a tu caso:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $original = 'Goat cheese salad with tomato';
    ?>
    <div id="$original"><?php echo $original ?></div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      var traducido;
      function translateText(response) {
        traducido = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
        //document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + traducido;
        fetch('translate_bd.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: "text=" + traducido
          })
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(data=>document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML = data);      
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      var $original = escape(document.getElementById("$original").innerHTML);
      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=--My API Key--&source=en&target=es&callback=translateText&q=' + $original;
      newScript.src = source;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
```

Es una forma más adecuada de "meter" el php dentro del flujo javascript.